# different with insert active records

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

Can someone explain simply the difference with

```
$this->actions->add_record($some)
```

and

```
$this->db->insert($some)
```

as far as I am aware they both insert data, but im not sure the difference and cant find a good explanation online

Comment: `actions->add_record` where did you get that ??

Comment: i never heard about CI has that kind of method

Comment: Are you really using CI? Can you give me the link i'm interesting.

Comment: @teckwei is above comment belongs to me ??

Comment: @AbdullaNilam No. I comment to the author. Cause I also never heard that as well. I think the method is from active record?

Comment: @teckwei ok ok. its seems me like model call. Don't know whats exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$this->actions->add_record($some);
```

is user defined function 
but

```
$this->db->insert($some);
```

is a built in function of Codeigniter's *[Query Builder Class](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#inserting-data)* and inserts data into a table like this:

```
$this->db->insert('users',array('name'=>'john));
```